# How to change Python version in Anaconda, install Numpy and sklearn 0.17?

Tags: python-3.x, installation, anaconda

[image]
I'm new to machine learning. I literally have no idea what I'm doing but I need tools to understand how machine learning works.

1. I just download Anaconda Python from [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r9tyA.png). I saw that the version I downloaded is 3.7 but I need a 3.5.
2. I don't really understand how to install Numpy 1.10 as well as sklearn 0.17

Can you please guide me how to install these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way to do this is by [using a custom conda environment](https://docs.conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html). You can do this by either of the following:

- install the [full version of Anaconda](https://www.anaconda.com/distribution/#download-section) (the *current version* with Python 3.7)
- install [Miniconda for a much smaller download](https://docs.conda.io/en/latest/miniconda.html)

Then open Anaconda Prompt in the Windows start menu. Then do:

`conda create -n customenvname python=3.5 numpy=1.10 scikit-learn=0.17`

Follow the prompts.

To activate the new environment and get off and running, just do `conda activate customenvname`. You are now in a Python 3.5 environment with all the dependencies you need:

```bsh
(base) C:\Users\user>conda activate customenvname

(customenvname) C:\Users\user>python --version
Python 3.5.6 :: Anaconda, Inc.
(customenvname) C:\Users\user>conda list
# packages in environment at C:\Users\user\Miniconda3\envs\customenvname:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
blas                      1.0                         mkl
certifi                   2018.8.24                py35_1
mkl                       11.3.3                        1
numpy                     1.10.4                   py35_2
pip                       10.0.1                   py35_0
python                    3.5.6                he025d50_0
scikit-learn              0.17.1              np110py35_1
scipy                     0.17.1              np110py35_1
setuptools                40.2.0                   py35_0
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_4
vs2015_runtime            14.15.26706          h3a45250_0
wheel                     0.31.1                   py35_0
wincertstore              0.2              py35hfebbdb8_0
```

NOTE: the `mkl` package is an [optimization of some of the most used scientific computing libraries maintained by anaconda](https://docs.anaconda.com/mkl-optimizations/).

Comment: Wow thankyou! Really easy to follow! Thank you so much. All the love xx